# ActiveReports multi columns detail

Tags: activereports, componentone

My main report includes a subreport in the detail section.

This subreport is designed as follow:

```
ghHeader1

  ghHeader1.ColumnLayout = false; // this header span accross both detail columns
  ghHeader1.NewColumn = None
  ghHeader1.NewPage = None
  ghHeader1.RepeatStyle = OnPage

ghHeader2

  ghHeader2.ColumnLayout = true; // this header is specific to each columns of the detail section
  ghHeader2.NewColumn = None
  ghHeader2.NewPage = None
  ghHeader2.RepeatStyle = None
  ghHeader2.ColumnGroupKeepTogether = true
  ghHeader2.GroupKeepTogether = true
  ghHeader2.KeepTogether = true

detail Section

  detail.ColumnCount = 2
  detail.ColumnDirection = DownAcross  
  detail.NewColumn = None
  detail.NewPage = None

gfFooter2

  gfFooter2.NewColumn = After
  gfFooter2.NewPage = None
  gfFooter2.ColumnLayout = true

gfFooter1

 gfFooter1.NewColumn = None
 gfFooter1.NewPage = None
 gfFooter.ColumnLayout = false
```

Now, my problem is that with this configuration, when the second column is printed, instead of adding a new group under the first printed column (on the left of the page) it creates a new page even if there is enough space to print the group on the same page.

How can I make the next group print on the same page in the first column ?

[image]

I'm using ActiveReports 7.1.7572. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is being caused due to the setting of "GroupKeepTogether" property. If you will check the details about this property [here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.GroupHeader~GroupKeepTogether.html), you will notice that enabling this property attempts to fit the groupheader and its footer on the same page. If they do not fit then it moves the complete section to the next page.

I tested this issue by creating a similar report but unfortunately could not reproduce the issue. Should you require further assistance, you can post your issue over the GrapeCity [support forums](http://our.componentone.com/groups/forum/reporting/activereports-7/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in the end as I know the position of each group, I chose to add all the controls programmatically in the ReportStart event.